# How to loop through rows in dataframe while using google API

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like following:

```
Address           Unit    Zipcode
111 west street    1A      12312
132 east street    NaN     13333
90 3rd avenue      PH      22222
```

And I have a code to format this address using Google API:

```
data['input'] = data['Address'] + ', ' + data['Unit'] + ', NY, '+data['Zipcode'].map(str)
df = list(data['input'])
addList = []
formatted = ''

for index in range(len(data)):
    try:
        jsonData = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + df[index] + '&key=D3fsldk3FJDISDKfjeisl')
        jsonData = jsonData.content
        jsonData = json.loads(jsonData)
        data.loc[index,'formatted'] = jsonData['results'][0]['formatted']

    except:
        ("No Address")
```

And When I run this I get:

```
Address           Unit    Zipcode   input
111 west street    1A      12312     111 west street, 1A 12312
132 east street    NaN     13333     NaN
90 3rd avenue      PH      22222     90 3rd avenue, PH 22222
```

However, I don't get the second "123 east street 13333" because the Unit is a NULL value.
My expected output would be:

```
Address           Unit    Zipcode   input
111 west street    1A      12312     111 west street, 1A 12312
132 east street    NaN     13333     132 east street, 13333
90 3rd avenue      PH      22222     90 3rd avenue, PH 22222
```

I have tried to insert for loop, however, i have an error.

```
for idx, row in data.iterrows():
    if data['Unit'].isna() == True:
        data['input'] = data['Address'] + ', NY, '+ data['Zipcode'].map(str)
    else:
        data['input'] = data['Address'] + ', ' + data['Unit'] + ', NY, '+data['Zipcode'].map(str)

data['formatted'] = ''
df = list(data['input'])
addList = []

for index in range(len(data)):
    try:
        jsonData = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + df[index] + '&key=D3fsldk3FJDISDKfjeisl')
        jsonData = jsonData.content
        jsonData = json.loads(jsonData)
        data.loc[index,'formatted'] = jsonData['results'][0]['formatted']

    except:
        ("No Address")
```

The error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any help will be appreciated..!

Comment: Can't you just use fillna() to change the NA to ''

Comment: But I get empty "East 7th Street, , NY, 10009" , , in between the address.... I need to format it a certain way to match with other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `np.where` such as:

```
data['input'] = np.where(data['Unit'].isna(), 
                         data['Address'] + ', NY, '+ data['Zipcode'].map(str), 
                         data['Address'] + ', ' + data['Unit'] + ', NY, '+data['Zipcode'].map(str))
```

Comment: It still gives me the same output, such as "East 7th Street, , NY, 10009", that , , in between....

Comment: did you `fillna` before? because no need here